# Laravel auth logging out radomlly

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a big problem, im loging users using laravel auth

```
\Auth::login($user, true, 120);
```

And its logging me out radomlly, i don't know why.
Sometimes is 1 minute and sometimes is 30 minutes, meaby problem is with using Auth::check() to many times per x time ?
Any ida ?

My sessions conf :

```
'lifetime' => 1440,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Versions:

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "GuzzleHttp/guzzle": "^6.1",
    "andywer/js-localization": "dev-laravel-5",
    "invisnik/laravel-steam-auth": "2.*"
},
```

Im using nginx

Comment: Strange. I have never used `login` method, what I always do is [auth::attempt](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users). Try this one, never had any issues.

Comment: You mean \Auth::attempt($user, true, 120);  ??

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? It seems the [Login method](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/StatefulGuard.html#method_login) has no third parameter. Also, you are setting `$remember` to  `true`, so a cookie will make sure the user stays logged in.

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.2.*" . Without third param is still not working correct.